# How to check author role in Views PHP

Tags: users, views

I need to check author role using views php. I've already added a relationship and added a field(excluded from view) User: role. How can I check if author role is equal to 'administrator'?

Answer (score 0):

I've added in Value Code:

```
$user_load = user_load($row->uid);
$var = $user_load->roles;
return $var;
```

then I've used in Output code:

```
print_r($value[3])
```

to get the string